# Parse date string to remove hours, minutes and seconds from timestamp

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

Suppose I receive from a web server a string to parse. This string contains a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
What I want is to convert it to the timestamp that represents the begin of that day,  hence I don't want seconds, minutes and hours.

As a dummy example, I'm trying to extract the timestamp of the current day, once converted to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Here's the code:

```
#include <chrono>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <iomanip>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    // Current time at GMT
    std::time_t now = std::time(0);
    std::tm *now_tm = std::gmtime(&now);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    // Extract yyyy-mm-dd = %F
    oss << std::put_time(now_tm, "%F");
    // Use oss to get a date without seconds from
    // current time at gmt
    std::tm tm;
    std::istringstream ss(oss.str());
    ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%F");
    std::time_t current_date = std::mktime(&tm);
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cd: " << current_date << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2017-10-19
cd: 1908337984324104
```

The extracted timestamp is clearly wrong. Where's the problem in the parsing the `2017-10-19` string using the `%F` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) lists no conversion specifier %F. When checking the stream flag (which you always should do!), it will also tell that the conversion failed, at least with my compiler.

So by replacing it with %Y-%m-%d, the conversion succeeds. Finally, you default-constructed the tm variable without zeroing it (e.g. by value-initialization). When fixing this as well, the code works as expected:

```
#include <chrono>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <iomanip>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    // Current time at GMT
    std::time_t now = std::time(0);
    std::tm *now_tm = std::gmtime(&now);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    // Extract yyyy-mm-dd = %F
    oss << std::put_time(now_tm, "%Y-%m-%d");
    // Use oss to get a date without seconds from
    // current time at gmt
    std::tm tm{ }; // value-initialize!
    std::istringstream ss(oss.str());
    ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d");
    if(!ss) std::cout << "conversion error\n";
    else {
        std::time_t current_date = std::mktime(&tm);
        std::cout << current_date << '\n';
        std::cout << "cd: " << current_date << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d86aa1e1d890a14d

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking at the documentation of another time-formating function, guessing that it would be the same. I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without leaving the safety of the `chrono` type system by using [Howard Hinnant's, free, open-source, header-only chrono-extension library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream ss{"2017-10-19"};
    date::sys_seconds tp;
    ss >> date::parse("%F", tp);
    std::cout << date::format("%F\n", tp);
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << "cd: " << tp.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

`date::sys_seconds` is a `std::chrono::time_point` that counts `chrono::seconds` in [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  You can parse directly into it using `%F`.  You can also format it, using the same format string (`%F`), and also inspect the underlying count of `chrono::seconds`.  This program outputs:

```
2017-10-19
cd: 1508371200s
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your suggestion. Keep my upvote